# need help with regex in javascript to replace string pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery

Need help with regex javascript , i tried few but didn't work

i want to replace the the following string which is a url. The values **200, 400**  are dynamic in the below string

`url=http://www.test.com?debug=true&MAXWIDTH:200+MAXHEIGHT:400`

with ,900 , 900 always and the result should be

after regex i want the url string contains the below value

```
url=http://www.test.com/?debug=true&MAXWIDTH:900+MAXHEIGHT:900
```

Comment: Should `httP//` be `http://`?

Comment: sorry rocket , that was a typo error..

Comment: Thanks to all who took time to answer my problem , really appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var replaceMaxWidthAndHeight = function(str, newWidthAndHeight) {
  var i=0;
  return str.replace(/\s*(MAXWIDTH|MAXHEIGHT)\s*:\s*(\d+)\s*/g, function(s, m1) {
    return m1 + ':' + newWidthAndHeight[i++];
  });
};

var s1 = "url=http://www.test.com/?debug=true&MAXWIDTH:200+MAXHEIGHT: 400";
var s2 = replaceMaxWidthAndHeight(s1, [900, 900]);
s2; // => "url=http://www.test.com/?debug=true&MAXWIDTH:900+MAXHEIGHT:900"
s2 = replaceMaxWidthAndHeight(s1, [10, 20]);
s2; // => "url=http://www.test.com/?debug=true&MAXWIDTH:10+MAXHEIGHT:20"
```

Comment: @maerics , can we do a check for MAXWIDTH AND MAXHEIGHT , it should be followed by those string , i have lot of values in the url , i don't want to replace all of them

Comment: @maerics , can you explain your code , i didn't understand [10,20]

Comment: @kobe: if you ever change from using the value 900 to needing dynamic values for the new width and height, you can pass them in as the second argument.  See my updated answer.

Comment: @kobe: `[10, 20]` is an array of 2 numbers, it can be anything.  In your case it would be `[900, 900]`.

Answer (score 2):

If you want replace it ignoring the order or if both are there:

```
str = str.replace(/(MAXWIDTH:|MAXHEIGHT:)\d+/g, '$1900');
```

Answer (score 1):

If `MAXWIDTH` and `MAXHEIGHT` *always* appear in the url as `MAXWIDTH:200+MAXHEIGHT:400`, then this regex will work.

```
var string = "url=http://www.test.com?debug=true&MAXWIDTH:200+MAXHEIGHT:400";
string.replace(/MAXWIDTH:\d*\+MAXHEIGHT:\d*/, 'MAXWIDTH:900+MAXHEIGHT:900');
```

Comment: @rockets, thanks very much this is what i want , i want to replace if it finds maxwidth and maxheight..

Answer (score 1):

Replace

```
(url=http://www.test.com\?debug=true&MAXWIDTH:)\d*(\+MAXHEIGHT:)\d*
```

with

```
$1900$2900
```

(being $1 and $2 the back references to the matching groups

EDIT: Thanks to Rocket

```
string.replace(/(url=http:\/\/www.test.com\?debug=true&MAXWIDTH:)\d*(\+MAXHEIGH‌​T:)\d*/, '$1900$2900')
```

Comment: Maybe you should put the code in your answer... `string.replace(/(url=http:\/\/www.test.com\?debug=true&MAXWIDTH:)\d*(\+MAXHEIGHT:)\d*/, '$1900$2900')`

Answer (score 1):

Or a more general solution:

```
function replaceValue(str, label, value) {
    rX = new RegExp("\\s*" + label + "\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)\\s*");
    return(str.replace(rX, label + ":" + value);
}

url = replaceValue(url, "MAXHEIGHT", 900);
url = replaceValue(url, "MAXWIDTH", 900);
```