# Using regex put string after a pattern

Tags: javascript, regex

I want to add a string `{something}` to a string if it contains `href="` or `href='`.

*Note - There could be space around the `=`.*

So, if my input is `<a href="http://google.com">Click</a>`

The output should be `<a href="{something}http://google.com">Click</a>`

So far, I have this regular expression which matches with what I want to match, but don't know how to add the string after the matching part.

```
/href\s*=\s*(\"|\')/
```

I checked [need help with regex in javascript to replace string pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6115955/need-help-with-regex-in-javascript-to-replace-string-pattern)

Comment: Why don't you use the DOM to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General answer, following off of your attempt:

```
string.replace(/href\s*=\s*(\"|\')/, "href=$1{something}");
```

(The `$1` simply references the captured group, whatever matched your parenthesized expression in your regex)

*Correct* way to modify an element's href:

```
element.href = '{something}' + element.href;
```

Comment: Thanks, and in my case, I wanted to preserve all the spaces, so this is what I followed - `string.replace(/(href\s*=\s*[\"|\']\s*)/,"$1{something}");`   For beginners - I am using capturing group - The entire pattern inside the first bracket is captured as $1 - `href\s*=\s*[\"|\']\s*` and I add `{something}` after it.

Comment: and btw, I am not modifying an anchor tag in the dom. I am modifying the text of an input field. The anchor tag appears in the content. Not sure if DOM manipulation using `element.href` will work here.

Comment: @Sandeepan You can't replace the parentheses with square brackets around the quotation marks like that—that causes all the characters inside the square brackets to match literally, including the pipe (`|`). You can instead do this `/(href\s*=\s*["']\s*)/`, which will match one of the characters in the 'character set', in this case one of the quote marks